# Maven failed on already deleted files

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I'm working on an Android project using eclipse (the official ADT) and compiling it using Maven. Up till now everything was OK.
Then I deleted some files and some packages and the weirdest thing happened.
compiling the project using

```
mvn clean install
```

Which I always use provided errors in files I deleted. example:

```
[ERROR] /path/to/file.java:[9,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class SomeClass
[ERROR] location: package path.to.package
```

Where the file, the class and the package are all deleted!
Also, when searching for them in Eclipse I do get the code, which is very weird, since I deleted it from the disk.
Does anyone know what's wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: You sure you deleted the file from the source and not the target folder? Did you check whether they are on the disk? Did you refresh project in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. They are deleted from the disk. I refreshed the project in Eclipse. I even went further to completely delete the entire project from the workspace, delete it from the disk, and it's metadata and add it as a new project. Still getting the same mysterious errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
For some unknown reason the project was not synchronized with the SVN repository and when I tried to commit the removal of the files it reverted them instead, so they were actually on the disk, though I didn't see them for some reason (probably refreshing problem)

1. Revert the missing files
2. Right-click the project->team->cleanup
3. Delete them **in Eclipse**
4. Commit the root folder (I could not commit them separately), notice their "Content" is "Deleted" and not "Missing"

HTH